# Number of downloads in Google Play for a specific range of dates

Tags: android, google-play

In statistics, I can see default dates when I choose 7 days, 30 days, 1 year or lifetime but it is non-editable. If it is possible to see number of downloads only for a custom range from `date1` to `date2` how can I do it?

Comment: Use google analytics in your app if you want to track installs for custom dates. Or use the developer console android app. It provides you with 30,60,90 days.

Comment: I have already published app. Yes, but I want a custom date range. In other words I want to choose the start and end dates.

Comment: You don't have that option. The max you can get is 7,30,60,90 days on the developer console app. Or you could export the full data on an excel file and use filters in that.

Comment: Yes this is what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, but I am sure there is an easier way.

I go to statistics->download->latest monthly report

Manually add the sum of `Daily user installs` for the days or months you want.